# Is the Else part of Case When statement ignored in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, case-when

Why "else" part is not working I don't understand. Normally it should returns reverse of numbers if case statement not provided.

Here is my code;

```
select Id,
       case 
         when mod(Id,10)<(Id/10) 
           then (cast((Id/10) as number(5))*10)+(mod(Id,10)) 
         else 
           mod(Id,10)*10+(Id/10)  
       end Col
from digits
```

[image: Sample Data]

Sample data;

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Id INT
);

insert into test
select 21 from dual
UNION ALL
select 12 from dual
UNION ALL
select 34 from dual
UNION ALL
select 43 from dual
UNION ALL
select 29 from dual
UNION ALL
select 92 from dual;
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: That is a CASE **expression** in a SQL statement. Not a CASE _statement_ in  a PL/SQL procedure

Comment: `mod(Id,10)` will never return any value larger than 9. With your data `((Id/10)*10)` will always be 10 or larger. I.e. `else` will never be reached.

Comment: @jarlh was just writing exactly the same thing! Although if Id < 10, ((Id/10)*10) will be 0.

Comment: Thanks friends, pls correct my code for me. I get this status in pl sql, same problem is not valid for t-sql.

Comment: sample input and output what u required .. As this  case statement is working as accepted ..

Comment: I added the sample data to my question..

Comment: Yes, but we don't know *what you're trying to do*, since all we have to try to reason from it is a query that **we know is wrong**.

Comment: Just I try to write a sample query to get distinct numbers from the table.

Comment: @aprkturk . . . Just look at the results of the arithmetic (http://rextester.com/ERKWV25819).  The `case` expression is doing the logic correctly.

Comment: I edited my query. Not it is working.. Thank you all guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reversing the integers with two digits the `case` should look like(notice the `trunc` function):

```
select  
   Id,
   case 
     when mod(Id,10)<(Id/10) 
       then trunc(Id/10)*10+mod(Id,10) --this is the number itself, Id
     else 
       mod(Id,10)*10+trunc(Id/10)  --reverse :)
   end Col
```

Answer (score 1):

@aprkturk you mentioned T-SQL; here is Florin's answer translated:

```
select  
   Id,
   case 
     when Id % 10 < Id / 10
       then Id / 10 * 10 + Id % 10  -- this is the number itself, Id
     else 
       Id % 10 * 10 + Id / 10       -- reverse :)
   end Col
from @i
order by Id
```

What is this for?  It seems an odd sort of thing to want to do...